# How to follow Linux (minshall french) symlinks in windows

Tags: linux, windows, cifs, symlink

I have a `CIFS` drive mounted in `linux` and `Windows` with the following, respectively,

- `sudo mount -t cifs -o mfsymlinks,cred=/home/user/.cifs_user  //server/folder /mnt/test`
- `net use M: \\server\folder /p:yes`

I can create and follow symbolic links in linux:

```bash
pushd /mnt/test
echo "test data" > test.dat
ln -s test.dat link-to-test.dat
cat link-to-test.dat
```

returns `test data` as expected.  Perfect!

Now, if on the `Windows` machine I open a `gitbash` terminal and write

```
cat link-to-test.dat
```

then I get the `Minshall+Finch` file

```
XSym
0008
729c5ad9d7fa8a171d3347aafa875f33
test.dat
```

Likewise if I run the same command from `Powershell`.

So the question: what do I have to do  for `Windows` to *follow* the links in the same way that `linux` does?

Comment: Do you mean easily follow?

Comment: @GregAskew: Ideally easily follow, but hard following is okay too.  The only way I have managed so far is to mount the directory in a linux container